# return elements from OnetoOne and ForeignKey Query using Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the three tables below and i am trying to write a query(or multiple queries) that would return all the `address` and `events` fields from their respective tables.

```
class Activity(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Event(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  start_time = models.TimeField()
  duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
  activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="activities")

class Address(models.Model):
  event = models.OneToOneField(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This is what i tried but it does not seem to be appropriate, it crashes!

```
    adds = Address.objects.all()
    for ad in adds:
        for events in ad.event.all():
            print("events", events)
```

is there a better way to do it? how can i achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Well, you have a `OneToOneField` on `Address`, so you can have only one `Event` per `Address`

Comment: @BernardoDuarte correct thats why i was wondering if this is possible with this logic. I need that one `event` but for each instances of `Event`

Comment: So do you want to keep the `models.py` structure or can it change?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte feel free to change it, but the idea was to have only `event` per `address` so the user can not use multiple address for the same event when it occurs. (might be doing this wrong) thanks

Comment: @cu__007 since Address and Event are in a One to One relationship you can get an addresses event by `address.event` (address is an instance of Address) and the reverse `event.address` No need to use `.all()` here as there is only one related object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a `OneToOneField` on `Address`, so you can have only one `Event` per `Address`.

Right now, what you can do is:

```
adds = Address.objects.all()
for ad in adds:
  event = ad.event # you only have one event per address
```

I would suggest that you change your `models.py` to:

```
class Address(models.Model):
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Event(models.Model):
  date = models.DateField()
  start_time = models.TimeField()
  duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
  address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events')

class Activity(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
  event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='activities')
```

This way you have only one `Address` per `Event`, but you can use the same address to multiple `Event`s, and you have multiple `Activity`s per `Event`.

Now to issue all events by address you can do:

```
addresses = Address.objects.all()
for addr in addresses:
  for event in addr.events.all():
    print('event', event)
```